# Probability Question with binomial Distribution?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Q: Scientists collecting butterfly samples near a nuclear power plant found that wing and antenna defects were somewhat common. Of ninety-eight butterflies collected in the sampling, three showed at least one defect. If a previous study on butterflies found near the same nuclear power plant thirty years found that there was one defect per thousand butterfly, what is the probability of finding seven in a sample of ninety-eight?

- So I found the probability of finding a defect in present time: 3/98 = 0.0306
- Then I found the probability of the study 30 years ago: 1/1000 = 0.001
- I ignored the 3/98 statistic at the beginning b/c I think it's irrelevant
- Then I found the probability of observing 7/98 which is 0.07143
- I then multiplied 0.07143 and 0.001 together and got 0.007143% as my answer

I'm confused as to how a binomial distribution can be used in this problem... unless my answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $1/1000$ as the probability that any particular butterfly will have a defect.

You are told that for the sample of ninety eight, *at least* three do have the defect, and wish to know the probability that *exactly seven* do when *given that condition*.

That is, find $\mathsf P(X=7\mid X\geq 3)$ when $X\sim\mathcal {Bin}(98, 1/1000)$.